# How can I pull out certain items from rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm writing a lib that has rxjs as a dependency. It only uses `Subject` - Is it possible for me to extract that one feature and include it within my lib, removing the need for rxjs as a dependency?

Answer (score 2):

No. check inner dependencies `Subject` rely on (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L1-L8). It is pretty much requiring most of primitives in rx.

Put aside of availability, if you're depends on rxjs, what reason you'd like to not to specify it as dependency?

Comment: The library is ~160kb and needs to be bundled into my script. My script is 5kb so it's a little overkill - was hoping for a lighter solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using Webpack's tree shaking feature did it for me.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

My Webpack configuration:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: './dist/dist.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader" ,
                query: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                    plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
}
```

And specified the location of the import like:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/subject"
```

Rather than

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs"
```

Bundle size went from `213kb` to `14kb`